# Struct value won't change when calling a method

Tags: c#

I have a struct which holds animation data. In the struct i have a method to change the animation time but for some reason the value never actually changes. Not sure i understand why that is the case.

```
public struct AnimationCommand
{
    float _duration;
    Action _onCompleteCallback;
    Action<float> _onUpdateCallback;

    public float Duration => _duration;

    public AnimationCommand(float animationTime, Action onComplete = null, Action<float> onUpdate = null)
    {
        _duration = animationTime;
        _onCompleteCallback = onComplete;
        _onUpdateCallback = onUpdate;
    }

    public void SetDuration(float animationTime) => _duration = animationTime;
}
```

In my class i have this:

```
    /*AnimationData is a property in base class 

    [SerializeField]
    AnimationCommand _animationData;
    protected AnimationCommand AnimationData => _animationData;
    */

    float delta = 10; //test value
    AnimationData.SetDuration(delta);
    Debug.Log(delta + " :: " + AnimationData.Duration);
```

The output i get is `10 :: 0`

Why does it not change the value? I assumed calling the method on the struct would change the value and avoid the value copy semantics that structs have ? Am i wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Public variable of struct is not changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127088/public-variable-of-struct-is-not-changing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `protected AnimationCommand AnimationData => _animationData;`

this will return copy of the `_animationData`.
Therefore, `AnimationData.SetDuration(delta);` becomes as "get the copy and modify it". So, the original does not changed.

Comment: Ah i see, does properties support `ref` keyword at all? if not i guess i'll just make the backing field protected.

Comment: I don't know about "property with `ref` keyword".
But, I think, if you want to **refer** the object, using `class` instead of `struct` may be simple way.
Or, the base class could provide method/property which call `_animationData.SetDuration()`.

Comment: Structs are _Value Types_. It's best to make Value types _immutable_. This is, as you found out, because they spin of copies during assignment (and similar operations). Use a class (a reference type) instead.

Comment: I need to use structs because in unity their ECS / Job System is entirely struct based and does not use classes.