# Why cant I modify Transform.position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class MoveAbleButtonSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform ObjectToMove;
    public bool moveLeft = true;
    public bool moveRight = false;
    public float SpeedToMove = 1f;

    private bool pressed = false;
    public float minZ = 0f;
    public float maxZ = 0f;

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        pressed = true;
    }

    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        pressed = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Transform T = ObjectToMove.transform;

        if (pressed && moveLeft)
        {
            T.Translate(Vector3.forward * SpeedToMove * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        }else
        if(pressed && moveRight)
        {
            T.Translate(Vector3.back * SpeedToMove * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        }

        if(T.position.z > maxZ)
        {
            T.position.z = maxZ;
        }

    }
}
```

Assets\Scripts\MainMenu\MoveAbleButtonSystem.cs(42,13): error CS1612: Cannot modify the return value of 'Transform.position' because it is not a variable

I dont get why I cannot change the position. All I want to do is for the ObjectToMove to move until it passes a certain point, after what it is not supposed to move anymore. Using Clamp provides the same error.

Comment: You can't just set x, y, or z, because the type of `position` is an immutable vector3 struct; you can assign a new vector to `position` though.

Comment: `Transform.position` is a struct return from a property getter, which means that a COPY of the position is returned. Attempting to change the data in the copy will have no effect on the original, so the compiler doesn't allow it.

Comment: Compiler would allow it though, if the struct were mutable. Problem is that x, y, z members have no setter at all.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon The `vector3` class in Unity [is NOT immutable](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-x.html). See the sample code in the link where the 'x' field is modified.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14945118/cant-change-structs-members-value-inside-generic-collections#answer-14958238

Comment: And this: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1078528/cannot-modify-the-return-value-of-transformpositio.html

Comment: @MatthewWatson interesting, assumptions shattered!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following simplified example demonstrates the same compile error:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var container = new Container();
        container.Property.Value = 1; // Error CS1612 - Cannot modify the return value of 'Container.Property' because it is not a variable
    }
}

public struct Item
{
    public int Value;
}

public class Container
{
    public Item Property { get; set; }
}
```

This is the issue you're seeing. It's happening because the `Container.Property` property is returning a copy of a value type, in this case `struct Item`.

Because this is a *copy* of the item stored in `Container` and not the item itself, changing the copy's properties cannot have any visible effect because the value returned from the property is not stored anywhere - no variable is assigned from it.

Therefore the compiler gives an error, to avoid misleading and useless code.

[The documentation for Error CS1612](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1612) explains all this in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Others - and the [error documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1612) - already explained the issue and the **why** in detail.

But in terms of a solution for your issue you would go e.g.

```
// Get copy of current position
var position = T.position;

if(position.z > maxZ)
{
    // modify the copy
    position.z = maxZ;
}

// assign back / apply modified value
T.position = position;
```

You could even combine and simplify it a lot by doing e.g.

```
public enum MoveDirection
{    
    Left,
    Right
}

public MoveDirection direction;

void Update()
{
    if(pressed)
    {
        var T = ObjectToMove.transform;
        var position = T.position;

        var multiplier = direction == MoveDirection.Left ? 1 : -1;
        position.z = Mathf.Clamp(position.z + SpeedToMove * Time.deltaTime * multiplier);
 
        T.position = position;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the comments from Mathieu and Matthew, position is a struct field of the `calss Transform` and due to this reason you can not change its fields like this. If you want to understand why this is not working imagine that Unity's `Transform` and `position` objects look something like this:

```
struct Position
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int z;
}

class Transform
{
    public Position _position;
    public Position position 
    {
        get
        {
            return _position;
        }
        set
        {
            _position = value;
        }
    }
}
```

When you write `T.position.z` the `position` part is actually a value copy of the original `T`'s `position` variable returned by the property `getter`. So by changing the copy of `position` you will not get the desired effect of updating the `T.position`'s `z` field. Due to this reason C# it trying to help you by throwing an error in order to prevent a bug that is very hard to identify.

Answer (score -3):

You can not change the individual components of a `Vector3`. To do this, you will have to change all the components. i.e :

```cs
if (T.position.z > maxZ)
{
    T.position = new Vector3(T.position.x, T.position.y, maxZ)
}
```

Comment: You *can* change the individual components of a `Vector3` [as shown in sample code in the actual documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-x.html). What you *can't* do is directly change the fields/properties of a `struct` returned from a property.